# Store the currently selected tab and load it after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have the following code for the tabs:

```js
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var toggle;
    return toggle = new Toggle('.toggle');
  });

  this.Toggle = (function() {
    Toggle.prototype.el = null;

    Toggle.prototype.tabs = null;

    Toggle.prototype.panels = null;

    function Toggle(toggleClass) {
      this.el = $(toggleClass);
      this.tabs = this.el.find(".tab");
      this.panels = this.el.find(".panel");
      this.bind();
    }

    Toggle.prototype.show = function(index) {
      var activePanel, activeTab;
      this.tabs.removeClass('active');
      activeTab = this.tabs.get(index);
      $(activeTab).addClass('active');
      this.panels.hide();
      activePanel = this.panels.get(index);
      return $(activePanel).show();
    };

    Toggle.prototype.bind = function() {
      var _this = this;
      return this.tabs.unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        return _this.show($(e.currentTarget).index());
      });
    };

    return Toggle;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

```css
.toggle {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
.toggle .tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.toggle .tabs .tab {
  float: left;
  background: white;
  color: #777777;
  height: 31px;
  margin: 2px 8px 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .tabs .tab.active {
  color: #dd4b39;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dd4b39;
}
.toggle .panels .panel {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: none;
}
.toggle .panels .panel:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggle'>
  <div class='tabs'>
    <div class='tab active'>Tab 1</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 2</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 3</div>
    <div class='tab'>Tab 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panels'>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 1</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 2</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 3</div>
    <div class='panel'>Panel 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the above code works just fine.... The only thing I want to add is the ability to store the current selected tab and if a user refreshes/reloads the page I want the same tab containt to appear and not the first tab as it is doing currently.

What do I need to add to the above code in order to achieve this?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Which means that it doesn't save the state of your page. When users refresh the page, the state is gone. To save the state, you may try to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) APIs.

Comment: Or change url hash and parse hash on page load. Will make each tab bookmarkable that way also

Comment: By all means, there isn't a ready-made magic available. You need to code to save the page's state.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to "save" information between visits to a page.

The old-school (and therefore more broadly browser-supported) way is to use a cookie!  I'm sure you've heard of them :-)

The second, more modern, way is to use local storage.  There are a number of libraries that can help you manage local storage (search for `localForage` for one) or you can roll up your own, of course.

Comment: No need for a localStorage library for something this trivial. Also localStorage support is not an issue in 2019

Comment: this must be a comment :)

Comment: and sessionStorage should be considered

Comment: jesus, guys... downvote, much? lol.  I forgot localstorage support goes back that far and I *did* mention that he can roll up his own localStorage interface.  Also, I didn't mention sessionStorage because I felt the implication was for it to be saved across sessions.  Maybe I'm wrong and I deserve the downvotes, but I'm going to stand by my answer anyway :-D